# List all the invalid controls in Orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have 30 fields in my form. At the bottom of the form I have a button where if I click on it, it should display all the fields which are invalid. Invalid includes not filling the mandatory fields also.

Using `xforms:trigger` I can create a button and using `DOMActivate` even I can write `xforms:action`. But what should I write inside the `xforms:action` to list all invalid fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your own error summary by listening to events like `xforms-valid` and `xforms-invalid`, keeping track of which controls are valid and invalid. But this is not a trivial task, especially if you want to handle repeats, and even nested repeats. Fortunately, this work has been done already for you, and the code has been put in a reusable component: `<fr:error-summary>`.

If you are using Form Runner, the error summary is setup for you by default. Otherwise, see this documentation on [how to use the error summary](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/view/error-summary) component.

Comment: Hi Avernet, Thanks for responding. I am not using the Form Runner, but i think i can code with the <fr:error-summary> tag. Again great answer. Thanks very much.